# Centering positions of buttons inside Tkinter grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to write a connect four game for my project. I'm using `tkinter` without any previous experience. I'm using the `grid()` layout, with 3 rows(1st for the title, 2nd for buttons, and 3rd for canvas displaying my game), and 6 columns. 
The problem I came across is making buttons appear at the top of every column. Even the first button isn't at the middle of 1st column, and it is getting more and more off, with every next button. I thought that the columns would be the same width as they all hold exactly the same button.

`P1` is my class that holds the actual game board and number of row/columns as I plan to be able to change them.

I tried using `grid_rowconfigure` method like this:

```py
self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

But it seems to have no effect.

```py
#Main.py
class Game:
    def __init__(self, roows, columns):
        self.rows = roows
        self.columns = columns
        self.gameTable = [["x" for x in range(self.columns)] for y in range(self.rows)]
        self.which_row = [5 for x in range(self.columns)]
```

```py
from tkinter import *
import Main

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.master.title("connect four")
        self.grid()

        Tytul = Label(self, text="Hello", font=("Helvetica", 24), fg="medium blue")
        Tytul.grid(row=0, columnspan=6)

        for i in range(P1.columns):
            button = Button(self, text="▼")
            button.grid(row=1, column=i)
        #self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    def draw_gametable(self):
        canvas1 = Canvas(self, relief=FLAT, background="#D2D2D2",
                         width=P1.columns*100, height=P1.rows*100)
        canvas1.grid(row=2, columnspan=6)

        cellwidth = 100
        cellheight = 100

        for column in range(P1.columns):
            for row in range(P1.rows):
                if P1.gameTable[row][column] == "x":
                    color = "grey"
                elif P1.gameTable[row][column] == "z":
                    color = "yellow"
                elif P1.gameTable[row][column] == "c":
                    color = "Red"
                x1 = column * cellwidth
                y1 = row * cellheight
                x2 = x1 + cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + cellheight
                canvas1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="cornflower blue")
                canvas1.create_oval(x1 + 2, y1 + 2, x2 - 2, y2 - 2, fill=color,  
                                    tags="oval")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    P1 = Main.Game(6, 7)
    root = Tk()
    instance = Window(root)
    instance.draw_gametable()
    root.mainloop()
```

[This is how i would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6dYq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have seven columns but you make the canvas span only six. `columnspan` doesn't mean "how many *more* columns to span" but rather "how many columns *in total* to span".

If you make the canvas span all 7 columns, everything will line up:

```
canvas1.grid(row=2, columnspan=7)
```

Comment: Wow, i can't belive i missed it, thank you so much :)